# Display intermediary nodes and relationships when finding path between two nodes

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to return the relationships between nodes where there could be one or two hops between them.

More precisely, below, I'm trying to find links between User `userA` and a Repository that has a relationship with a Status.

```
match (u:User{login: "userA"})-[*..2]->(r:Repository)-[HAS_STATUS]->(s:Status) 
return *
```

The above query works and returns all the results, but does not display the relationship between the User and the Repository if there is an intermediate node.

Here's a screenshot of the results and what I mean visually:

[image]

Note that for some reason, where there is a *single* hop between the User and a Repository, the relationship is shown. It's the two hop relationships that are not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
match path=(u:User{login: "userA"})-[*..2]->(r:Repository)-[HAS_STATUS]->(s:Status) 
return path
```

About the “for some reason” : the Neo4j viz has an autocomplete that displays edges between neighbours. Even when these edges are not returned by the query.